# What causes midcycle FSH surge in the menstrual cycle?

Tags: embryology

I have encountered contradictory attributions to the causal factor of midcycle FSH surge. Whereas some sources attribute it to the relatively high estrogen levels (1), others say it is because of increasing amounts of progesterone (2).
I am confused.

(1) http://www2.hsc.wvu.edu/som/physio/classes/pcol260/classroom/notes/reproductive.htm

(2)
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK279054/#!po=1.17188

Answer (score 0):

The LH surge is began by a impressive rise of estradiol produced by the preovulatory follicle and results in subsequent ovulation.
The LH surge stimulates luteinization of the granulosa cells and stimulates the synthesis of progesterone responsible for the midcycle FSH surge.

Comment: If this is true, why are FSH levels kept low by progesterone and estrogen secreted by the corpus luteum in the mid- and late-luteal phases of the cycle?